# Search for components in the layout designer palette of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there any way to search for a component by name in the Android Studio layout designer palette?

Currently it is just a list of components grouped in some categories but there is even no sorting in the single groups.

I try to find the android.widget.SearchView component but fail to do so. I'm not sure whether I just miss it or it is not here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search for components in the Layout Design Palette of Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29590103/search-for-components-in-the-layout-design-palette-of-android-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's under Containers.

[image]

Yes it does not make sense.

And the list is hardcoded here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/master/android/src/com/intellij/android/designer/model/views-meta-model.xml
see the end of the document, and you will see the groupings. And yes this is very outdated, having `fill_parent` instead of `match_parent` everywhere.

Comment: Thanks ... honestly I have just skipped the containers part since it really made no sense to have it there. Again a filter field would be a very nice addition to the palette