# Search for components in the Layout Design Palette of Android Studio

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

Is there any way to search the components of the **Layout Design Palette** on **Android Studio** (when visually designing an Android Layout XML)?

[image]

*btw it was already asked here, but no answer received — [Search for components in the layout designer palette of Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28854834/search-for-components-in-the-layout-designer-palette-of-android-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Search the layout design palette

1. Focus the palette
2. Start typing for what you are looking for (e.g. `button`)
3. Use your up/down arrow key to jump to the previous/next search result

[image: search android studio palette]

Comment: Yeah, it's a new feature which didn't exist when I originally asked the question :) But, it's fair to say that as of now - your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

yes man, in your xml layout file not in design but in text, when you're writing your first letters android studio gives you a hint to what you are looking for...

for example you write " Rela... " and then press "Ctrl+Space" it automatically suggests Relative layout and so on.

Comment: Yeah, sure. I'm asking about the GUI - not XML :)